# Emacs - Can't Find Info About electric-layout-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm very new to Emacs, and I'm having trouble finding information about `electric-layout-mode`, specifically `electric-layout-rules`.

I use `c-toggle-auto-newline` right now, but I'm trying to replace this with Electric Layout in the hopes that it will cooperate with Electric Pair Mode, so that I can combine the autoindentation of `electric-indent-mode` with Electric Pair Mode's bracket behavior.

In other words, I am hoping it will give me this behavior upon pressing "{":

```
int main() <- (Ideally autonewline here, as C Auto Newline does)
{
    (point)
}
```

However, I can't find enough information about `electric-layout-rules` to get it working in my .emacs file.  I enabled `electric-layout-mode` without trouble, since there is an entry for it in the Customize buffer.

I looked at the Help entry for "electric-layout-rules", but I had trouble understanding it, and I noted that the syntax for it was similar to that of `c-hanging-braces-alist` of C Auto Newline, which I tried in vain to emulate the syntax of.

Long story short, I would appreciate some kind of use example for `electric-layout-rules`, something I might be able to put into my .emacs file.

---

**EDIT:** I had asked a [similar, less detailed version of this question](https://superuser.com/questions/602626/emacs-specific-bracket-behavior-customization/) on SuperUser a couple of weeks ago.  I don't know how to get questions moved, but I figured I might leave it open until this one is answered or if someone suggests that I delete it now, in case any of it is relevant here.

This [Electric Layout Mode Manual Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-for-Programs.html) was linked to in the other question, but I doesn't have anything on customizing the behavior through `electric-layout-rules`, and it explicitly says JavaScript on it.  The code in the answer and `electric-layout-mode` didn't work when editing a C file.

Comment: Congratulations using Emacs! Recommend to leave out all the electric stuff at the beginning, even if it reveals some of it strength. IMHO Emacs' major strength is extensibility, where electric is not the most suitable point to start with.

Comment: FWIW, I've just installed a fix for `electric-pair-mode` which makes it interact better with `electric-layout-mode`.  I can now get the behavior you want, although it sadly depends on the order in which the two modes are enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as you've seen, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `electric-layout-rules` <kbd>RET</kbd> tells us:

```
List of rules saying where to automatically insert newlines.
Each rule has the form (CHAR . WHERE) where CHAR is the char
that was just inserted and WHERE specifies where to insert newlines
and can be: nil, `before', `after', `around', or a function of no
arguments that returns one of those symbols.
```

which means that we can add new rules via the following pattern:

```el
(add-to-list 'electric-layout-rules '(CHAR . WHERE))
```

e.g.:

```el
(add-to-list 'electric-layout-rules '(?{ . around))
```

would cause newlines to be automatically inserted before and after a `{`, whenever we type it.

I tried combining the layout and pairs options, and it doesn't quite replicate what you were hoping for, but FWIW:

```el
(require 'electric)
(add-to-list 'electric-layout-rules '(?{ . around))
(add-to-list 'electric-pair-pairs '(?{ . ?}))
(electric-layout-mode 1)
(electric-pair-mode 1)
```

It seems to be sensitive to the order in which you enable those two modes. Adding a layout rule for the closing brace didn't help, as those evidentially only trigger on manually-typed characters.

Further reading:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Basic Char Syntax` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Dotted Pair Notation` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Association Lists` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't want to work with Electric Pair Mode after all this trouble.  The closest I can get is two brackets without the indented line between.  Do you think there is a better way to get the bracket behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: See edits. You might also look at throwing `electric-indent-mode` into the mix, but I don't know offhand if that works. There are other alternatives; see the Wiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs (or maybe something like [Yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) might be of interested?)

Comment: I already had `electric-indent-mode` on, so I'll just take a look at AutoPairs instead of trying to hammer all of these electric modes into working how I want.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You might also want to check out [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens), which is what all the cool kids are using (quoth Nic Ferrier). It sets out to be flexible and customisable.